# To check Which function is Call on hit on submit button

Tags: php, prestashop

I am developing the project in prestashop.I am new in prestashop.My code is given below:

```
<form action="{$link->getModuleLink('bankwire', 'validation', [], true)|escape:'html'}" method="post">
<p>
    <img src="{$this_path_bw}bankwire.jpg" alt="{l s='Bank wire' mod='bankwire'}" width="86" height="49" style="float:left; margin: 0px 10px 5px 0px;" />
    {l s='You have chosen to pay by bank wire.' mod='bankwire'}
    <br/><br />
    {l s='Here is a short summary of your order:' mod='bankwire'}
</p>
<p style="margin-top:20px;">
    - {l s='The total amount of your order is' mod='bankwire'}
    <span id="amount" class="price">{displayPrice price=$total}</span>
    {if $use_taxes == 1}
        {l s='(tax incl.)' mod='bankwire'}
    {/if}
</p>
<p>
    -
    {if $currencies|@count > 1}
        {l s='We allow several currencies to be sent via bank wire.' mod='bankwire'}
        <br /><br />
        {l s='Choose one of the following:' mod='bankwire'}
        <select id="currency_payement" name="currency_payement" onchange="setCurrency($('#currency_payement').val());">
            {foreach from=$currencies item=currency}
                <option value="{$currency.id_currency}" {if $currency.id_currency == $cust_currency}selected="selected"{/if}>{$currency.name}</option>
            {/foreach}
        </select>
    {else}
        {l s='We allow the following currency to be sent via bank wire:' mod='bankwire'}&nbsp;<b>{$currencies.0.name}</b>
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_payement" value="{$currencies.0.id_currency}" />
    {/if}
</p>
<p>
    {l s='Bank wire account information will be displayed on the next page.' mod='bankwire'}
    <br /><br />
    <b>{l s='Please confirm your order by clicking "I confirm my order".' mod='bankwire'}</b>
</p>
<p class="cart_navigation" id="cart_navigation">
    <input type="submit" value="{l s='I confirm my order' mod='bankwire'}" class="exclusive_large" />
    <a href="{$link->getPageLink('order', true, NULL, "step=3")|escape:'html'}" class="button_large">{l s='Other payment methods' mod='bankwire'}</a>
</p>
</form>
```

I want to know on click on submit button what function is call in controller.Any Idea to know the what function is call in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand the code. There in the beginning of the form comes the call to obtain the URL and indicates that this address points to the "bankwire" module, specifically to "validation".

Check the URL you on the form or the debugger opens your browser to see the URL that was sent.

https://github.com/PrestaShop/bankwire/blob/master/controllers/front/validation.php